# Как отправить eml во вложении

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Всем привет, пытаюсь отправить файл с расширением .eml через php mailer как вложение, приходит пустой файл. Файлы с другими расширениями отправляются нормально, пробовал отправить eml через веб интерфейс, пришел как надо. Есть идеи?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try{
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Username = '*********';
    $mail->Password = '*********';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    // от кого
    $mail->setFrom('************');
    // куда отвечать
    $mail->addReplyTo('*************');
    // куда отсылать
    $mail->addAddress('**************');
    // тема
    $mail->Subject = "тема 3";
    // тело письма
    $mail->msgHTML('text');
    $mail->addAttachment(__DIR__.'/noname1.eml');
    $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Решение вы можете опубликовать как __ответ__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eml шифровать не нужно, тогда файл считывается

```
$mail->addAttachment(__DIR__.'/noname1.eml', 'noname.eml', 'binary', 'message/rfc822');
```